# Does await keyword block execution of current method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've been reading about the use of `async-await` and there's one concept I'm not really sure I quite understood because most of the examples consider what happens to the execution of the calling method and not the actual `async` method.

Suppose I have this piece of code

```
...
var r1 = await httpClient.GetAsync(url1);
var r2 = await httpClient.GetAsync(url2);
...
```

Will the second GET request for `url2` be executed only after content of `url1` has been downloaded or can it be executed also before content of `url1` is downloaded?

In other words, will the following code call both URLs at the same time without waiting for the first one to finish and the "waiting" only happens at the `await r1`/`await r2` lines?

```
...
var r1 = httpClient.GetAsync(url1);
var r2 = httpClient.GetAsync(url2);

var response1 = await r1;
var response2 = await r2;
...
```

Lastly, can you confirm that there is a difference between these 2 pieces of code I provided?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what await is for. I recomment this article from Lippert : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx.It look long but it's a help in understanding away and async

Comment: And once you got addicted you can find more here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/async/. From your best provider of C# lesson Lippert

Comment: @DragandDrop That first link is dead

Comment: @Daan there is a space missing at the end of the link so there is an `.it` that should not be there : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx More than ( 5minute can't edit)

Comment: If you were the thread and your name is `T1`, here is what `await` means "T1: hey threadpool, ask one of your threads to do this and do not continue forward. Let me know once this is done. I am leaving because I need to something else." Sometime later, you are somewhere else but you will be interrupted. "PoolThread: Hey T1, I am done". You start exécution of the next line of code and notice it is another `await` and thus you say the same thing. It is not always a thread from the pool, but in most cases it is.

Comment: But it is not important how it is implemented and you should not bother with it, unless you need to.

Comment: @CodingYoshi For `await` its not mandatory that a Threadpool thread is required, it can be a Threadless operation for pure IO call using IO completion ports, which is the main use case for Async-Await. Thread Pool comes in the picture for in Memory / CPU bound operation, where something like `Task.Run`is awaited

Comment: @mrinalkamboj Correct and I mentioned that in the last sentence in my comment.